# Instruct SAPI to speak "space" character in spellout mode

Tags: sapi

I have a VC++ app, where I'm trying to let SAPI spell out some text, but it is ignoring the "space" character. Any way to let it actually say "space" when it finds one?

Sample text sent to the Speak function:

```
<spell>Hello, world</spell>
```

This will be spoken as "h e l l o comma w o r l d". The space was ignored. I want it to say "h e l l o comma space w o r l d".

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do this using   and the   tags.
see here 
[Controlling SAPI with XML](http://www.exceletel.com/support/whtpapers/speech/tapispch_P4.htm)
here's what I ended up with: (VBScript)

```
spell_my_text "oh N/o!"
sub spell_my_text (strText)
    set sapi = createobject ("sapi.spvoice")        
    for i = 1 to (len(strText))
    strmychar = mid(strText,i,1)
    if instr (1,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",strmychar,0) > 0 then          
        strmytext = "<spell>" & strmychar & "</spell>"
        sapi.speak "<xml>capital " & strmychar & "</xml>"
    else    
        sapi.speak "<spell>" & strmychar & "</spell>"
    end if
Next
```

end Sub